# Is the status bar required for iPad Pro Screenshots on the iOS app store?

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm developing an application and I was wondering if the iPad Pro screenshots required a status bar because it looks weird when your battery isn't full or the time always changes. (I can't use the simulator to create my screenshots because my app uses some libraries that can't be compiled for x86_64, i386). If I crop the status bar it doesn't meet the size requirements which is 2732 x 2048 for landscape or 2048 x 2732 for portrait.

Comment: You can use an app like Sketch to change the time and battery.

Comment: You'd rather resize the cropped png to 2732X2048

Comment: but If I remove the status bar is my app going to get rejected?

Comment: To my knowledge, it won't get rejected, because of that reason.

Comment: If the required size of the screenshot represents the full size of the iPad Pro, then this means that Apple has no issue with the status bar being part of the image since most apps show the status bar.